# How do I pass a variable into an ejs script tag attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-maps, ejs

I'm trying to pass an API Key - which I call on the server side and pass through to an EJS file - into the src attribute on a script tag. When I console.log the string it prints exactly how'd I want but I can't update the src attribute the way I need to, to be able to run the script. I've tried passing in the string variable directly, using template literals etc. Any ideas?

```
    <script>
        let myKey = <%- JSON.stringify(key) %>
        let string = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${myKey}&callback=initMap`
    </script>

    <script src= https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${myKey}&callback=initMap
    async defer> </script
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use javascript inside tag definition, you can write javascript only in between the script tag, hence the template literal or variable won't work inside src value of script tag

Besides, you can directly use values passed by your route inside HTML part

Write it like this in your code

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= key%>&callback=initMap"
    async defer> </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Still not getting the outcome, i'm looking for. Will have a play around using your approach.

Comment: You can share here if you have issues with this approach